# How to pass value from controller to a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my controller

```
var controller = app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.months = ["January", "February", "March", "April",
                "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                "October", "November", "December"];
}]);
```

This is my Directive

```
app.directive('monthDirective', function () {

return {

    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem) {

        var fromDate , toDate;
        scope.$watch('fromdate', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            fromDate = new Date(newValue);
            fromDate = moment(newValue, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
            console.log('newValue', newValue)
        });

        scope.$watch('todate', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            toDate = new Date(newValue);
            toDate = moment(newValue, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
            var range = moment.range(fromDate, toDate);
            console.log('toDate', toDate)
            range.by('months',function (moment) {
                moment.toArray('months');
                console.log('I am the array', moment.toArray('months'));
                var mom = moment.toArray('months');
                for (var i = 0; i <= scope.months.length; i++)
                {
                    for (var j = 0; j <= mom.length;j++)
                    {
                        if(scope.months[i] == mom[j][1])
                        {

                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        });

    }
  }
})
```

I want to get the access of `$scope.months(present in my controller)` in my directive to do some logic.

Can any one suggest me how to do this?

Comment: What do you actually need? Access to the parent scope or pass a variable to directive?

Comment: I need to get access of $scope.months (which is in controller) in the directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the directive does't create child scope. So You can access the scope of your controller by default:

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.test = 'test1';
});
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem) {
        console.log(scope.test)
    }
  }
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/5u2c3mYbLyAX4LIC82l2?p=preview

But [NexusDuck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37718717/6429253) is correct. A best practice is to use isolated scope for directive. So you can access the `months` by passing it in directive attribute

You can also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs). It is very detailed explanation of the scope inheriting.

Answer (score 3):

Though you could use a childscope or no scope, a best practice is to use an [isolated scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive):

```
app.directive('monthDirective', function () {

return {
    scope: {
      months: '='
    },
    //The rest
  }
});
```

Usage:

```
<div month-directive months="months"></div>
```

Comment: scope: true can be used too.

Comment: @Silvinus like I said, a childscope (scope: true) can be used as well but is a bad practice

Comment: Why bad ? It's depends of what you need. If your directive depends on a parent directive you can use scope: true. I agree with you if directive can be use in standalone.

Comment: @Silvinus Because then it can not be reused unless you name the scope properties in the parent controller the same in every location where you use the directive, thus creating a tight coupling

Comment: It's for that I said I agree with you only if directive can be use alone in other context. But in this case we don't know the use case...
I just want to say scope: true isn't a bad practice. It's depend of what you need